# Separate debug/release output in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I want to have separate output directories for debug and release builds. However, I don't see any proper option in FlashDevelop. Is this thing achievable, and if so, how to do this? If not, how to determine if current build is compiled as debug or release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add "-debug" in the output path (Project propoerties) it will be removed in release builds.

- **bin/app-debug.swf** or **bin-debug/app.swf**
- will be generated as **bin/app.swf** in Release mode

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Go to Project->Properties->Build. On the Post-Build Command Line, you can define what will happen after the build is complete. You should make a *.bat that will move the build to the corresponding folder, or execute the command directly.

For example, this command moves the built *.swf file to a debug or release folder, depending on the current build.

```
cmd.exe /c "xcopy /Y $(OutputDir)\$(OutputName) $(OutputDir)\$(BuildConfig)\"
```

If the directory doesn't exists, it will create it.

Hope this helps